# How to create user in terraform to send email with ses using smtp

Tags: terraform, smtp, amazon-ses

I need to have the ability to send Emails with SES

I have created the **aws_iam_policy_document**

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policy_companyweb_job" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "ses:SendEmail",
      "ses:SendRawEmail",
      "ses:ReadEmail",
      "ses:ReadRawEmail",
      "iam:CreateAccessKey",
      "iam:DeleteAccessKey",
      "iam:GetAccessKeyLastUsed",
      "iam:ListAccessKeys",
      "iam:UpdateAccessKey"
    ]
    resources = [
      "*"
    ]
  }
}
```

But how do I attach it to a User with an access key ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
#locals {
#  boundary_arn = "arn:aws:iam::${var.aws_account_id}:policy/PCSKPermissionsBoundary"
#}

resource "aws_iam_user" "company_web_ses_user" {
  name          = "company-web-ses-user"
  force_destroy = "true"
  #  permissions_boundary = local.boundary_arn
}

resource "aws_iam_access_key" "company_web_ses_user" {
  user = aws_iam_user.company_web_ses_user.name
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "company_web_ses_user_sender" {
  name        = "common_ses_sender"
  description = "Allows sending of e-mails via Simple Email Service"
  policy      = data.aws_iam_policy_document.policy_companyweb_job.json
}

resource "aws_iam_user_policy_attachment" "company_web_ses_attach" {
  user       = aws_iam_user.company_web_ses_user.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.company_web_ses_user_sender.arn
}

#resource "aws_ses_domain_identity" "mail-domain" {
#  domain = var.ses_domain_name
#}
#
#resource "aws_ses_domain_mail_from" "mail-from" {
#  domain           = aws_ses_domain_identity.mail-domain.domain
#  mail_from_domain = "bounce.${aws_ses_domain_identity.mail-domain.domain}"
#}
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}
```

Comment: Is this an answer to the question?  If so, it might help to add an explanation of how it solves the problem.